# How can I change styles in the onClick event?

Tags: reactjs, onclick, styles

I want to show/hide the search bar on the top side of the screen.
I am trying to implement an operation where the search bar is shown when the search button is pressed and hides again when the close button of the search bar is pressed.

```
  const showSearchBar = () => {
    document.querySelector("#hearder_search_bar").style = {
      top : 0
    }
  };

  const hideSearchBar = () => {
    document.querySelector("#hearder_search_bar").style = {
      top : -71
    }
  };

 return (
    <>    
      <form id = "hearder_search_bar" action="#" className="header__search">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search"/>
        <button
          type="button"
          class="search"
          onClick={...}
        >
        </button>
        <button 
          type="button" 
          className="close"
          onClick={hideSearchBar}
        >
      </form>

      <div className="header__action--search">
            <button 
              className="header__action-btn" 
              type="button"
              onClick={showSearchBar}>
            </button>
      </div>
    </>
 );
```

css

```
.header__search {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -71px;
}
```

Comment: You have to use state to implement this. Don't use the DOM API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use react useState hook and let react handle the manipulation of the DOM.

```
const [shouldShowSearch, setShouldShowSearch] = useState(false);
const toggleShowSearch = () => setShouldShowSearch(prev => !prev);
const label = shouldShowSearch ? 'hide' : 'show';
const top = shouldShowSearch ? '70px' : '0';
//... code
<>
<form id="hearder_search_bar" action="#" className="header__search" style={{top}}>
// ... code
<button 
          type="button" 
          className={label}
          onClick={toggleShowSearch}
        >
</form>
// .. code
<button onclick={toggleShowSearch}>{label} search</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but after insert ```const toggleShowSearch = setShouldShowSearch(prev => !prev);```, the following error appears.       [Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.]

Comment: Sorry, it is suppose to be: ``const toggleShowSearch = () => setShouldShowSearch(prev => !prev);``. Updated the code above.

Comment: Thanks, that's right.  but is there any way to change the initial state according to the width of the screen?
In pc(min-width : 1280), search_bar is showed from the beginning, and in mobile, search_bar is showed when button is clicked.

Comment: It is really hard to see what is going on without a live page, do you have a transition? If not just change the ``top`` style attribute to ``display``, and toggle the value between ``none/block``.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditionnal className

```
className={headerIsHidden ? 'header__search__hidden' : 'header__search__shown'
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I have already tried this way.